# Fastest way to calculate the count of records in child table based on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

**Table Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VMaster](
    [VID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [VName] [varchar](30) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TblMaster](
    [SID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL Primary Key,
    [VID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] default (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [CharToAdd] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Start] [int]  NOT NULL,
    [End] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TblDetails](
    [DetailsID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL Primary Key,
    [SID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Sno] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ConcatenatedText] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [isIssued] [bit] default (0) NOT NULL,
    [isUsed] [bit] default (0) NOT NULL
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TblMaster]  WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [fk_SI_id] FOREIGN KEY([VID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[VMaster] ([VID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TblMaster] CHECK CONSTRAINT [fk_SI_id]
GO
```

**Sample data:**

```
Insert into dbo.VMaster Values ('A1')
Insert into dbo.VMaster Values ('A2')
GO

Insert into dbo.TblMaster Values (1,default, 'ABC', 1, 5)
Insert into dbo.TblMaster Values (1,default, 'XYZ', 10, 20)
Insert into dbo.TblMaster Values (2,default, 'P1', 10, 15)
GO

Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(1, 1, 'ABC1', 1,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(1, 2, 'ABC2', 1,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(1, 3, 'ABC3', 1,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(1, 4, 'ABC4', 0,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(1, 5, 'ABC5', 0,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(2, 10, 'XYZ10', 1,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(2, 11, 'XYZ11', 1,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(2, 12, 'XYZ12', 1,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(2, 13, 'XYZ13', 1,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(2, 14, 'XYZ14', 1,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(2, 15, 'XYZ15', 0,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(2, 16, 'XYZ16', 0,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(2, 17, 'XYZ17', 0,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(2, 18, 'XYZ18', 0,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(2, 19, 'XYZ19', 0,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(2, 20, 'XYZ20', 0,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(3, 10, 'P110', 1,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(3, 11, 'P111', 1,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(3, 12, 'P112', 1,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(3, 13, 'P113', 1,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(3, 14, 'P114', 1,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(3, 15, 'P115', 1,0)
    GO
```

**Expected Output:**

[image]

**Query which I have as of now:**

```
SELECT 
    TM.VID, VM.VName, TM.CharToAdd, TM.Start, TM.[End],
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.TblDetails TD where TD.SID=TM.SID and isIssued = 0 ) Balance
FROM 
dbo.TblMaster TM, dbo.VMaster VM
Where VM.VID = TM.VID
```

I am trying to calculate total matching records in TblDetails for each VID whose isIssued value is 0.

1. User could select a period (date range) for which they want to see this output. For that TblMaster.CreatedDate is what we have to use.
2. Also user can select a specific VID and like to see the result only for that.
3. Just in case if date range or VID is not provided then this has to work against the whole table! Per month there might be 500000 records in TblDetails and we will hold 12 months of data.

Comment: It looks like the data does not support what you are trying to do.  In details the concat field shows ABC records and XYZ records on the same SID.  There are a total of 8 records in the child table with IsIssued = 1 and that is what your query returns.  What am I missing?  How do you get two?  Even just counting the records with ABC in concat there are three not two...

Comment: What does "It is not working" mean, exactly?   Include any error messages.

Comment: @JoeC Sorry about that. There are typos in my sample data. Will update it now.

Comment: Your query gives expected result

Comment: @TabAlleman No error message. Results weren't matching but looks like I had typos in the input data. Now the concern is filtering conditions and making the query faster as tblDetails is expected to have 500000 per month *12 months data.

Comment: @JaydipJ Thanks. Yes once I fixed the typos in the input data my query result is matching the expected output. Now the concern is how to add filtering conditions & having good performance while hitting a huge table.

Comment: @prasanth all the possible changes are made in below given Ans, this will apply all filter as per your conditions and will improve performance as well since Ans contains  Creation of `NONCLUSTERED ` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the summary of the whole table your query looks OK.

It is easy to add an optional filtering on top of that.

If parameter is `NULL`, it will be ignored. If parameter is not `NULL`, it will limit the result set:

```
DECLARE @ParamStart datetime = '2016-01-01';
DECLARE @ParamEnd datetime = '2017-01-01';
DECLARE @ParamVID int = NULL;

SELECT 
    TM.VID, VM.VName, TM.CharToAdd, TM.Start, TM.[End],
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.TblDetails TD where TD.SID=TM.SID and isIssued = 0) Balance
FROM 
    dbo.TblMaster AS TM
    INNER JOIN dbo.VMaster AS VM ON VM.VID = TM.VID
WHERE
    (TM.CreatedDate >= @ParamStart OR @ParamStart IS NULL)
    AND (TM.CreatedDate < @ParamEnd OR @ParamEnd IS NULL)
    AND (TM.VID = @ParamVID OR @ParamVID IS NULL)
ORDER BY TM.SID
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

To make it efficient, it should help to have this index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_] ON [dbo].[TblDetails]
(
    [isIssued] ASC,
    [SID] ASC
)
```

And also indexes on `dbo.TblMaster.CreatedDate` and `dbo.TblMaster.VID`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Sorry for the typo have updated it now. Now my query also seems to return the expected result. How to test which one is performing better when hitting a huge table?

Comment: I know only one method to test the performance - run the queries against a "huge" table and use stopwatch to measure the time.

Comment: If we add `AND (TM.VID = @ParamVID OR @ParamVID IS NULL)` this condition at joining this will also helps to filter data in faster way,isn't it?

Comment: @JaydipJ, I don't quite understand your question. If this condition significantly reduces the number of processed rows, then it should make the query faster. An index on `VID` column should make this filter efficient.

Comment: Yes exactly what I am trying to suggest